# Get cannot find the master page error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, master-pages

I have added master page to the project. Although I can successfully run the page, it doesn't switch to design view.

It gives me errors :

1)Cannot find the master page.
2)No build providers specified for the extension (They are added in both the applications and machine's web.config).
3)Can't switch to design view. Get an error cannot find a User Control. The UserControl is an dll, provided by the client for searching employees.

Comment: Do you mean user control (ascx) or custom control - AFAIK, user controls cannot be packaged in different assembly!

Comment: Thanks Vinay. Regarding the DLL, its a Control which gives Employee Details on Entering the Employee Information. It makes a Web Service Call to the HR Database. The application runs perfectly. I am not able to switch to Design View the ASPX Page. Is there any particular reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

Just Clean the Solutions of Project.And Buid the Application.Again Re-Build the Application.

```
Ctrl+Shift+B  --> To Build an Solution
Go to Build --> Clean Solution
```

Some times the Visual Studio get the intellisense problems.This is may also Like that i think otherwise there is nothing.